# Can't figure out query for this tables and relations

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My tables, relations and wanted results:
[image: My tables, relations and wanted results]

I want if it is possible, as you can see on the picture, to get this 1 row result.
If it is not possible then 2 rows result so later I can loop through to get 2 categories from 2 rows.

I can't figure out right SQL_QUERY to this.

I don't know how create query to have wanted results.

How this query should look like?

Or maybe it is bad way to get data like this, and I should make this in 2 queries instead of 1 query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use group_concat and group by

```
select p.*, group_concat(c.nazwa)
from posts p
inner join posts_categories pc on pc.id_posta = p.id
inner join categories c on c.id = pc.id_kategorii
group by p.id
```

Comment: #1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax obok '-categories pc on pc.id_posta = p.id
inner join categories c on c.id = pc.id_ka' in line 3

Comment: Okay, you just mistaken table names in your query, I changed to right one and this works great. Thank you :D. Nice